# Not viewing Table Layout from a csv in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am making an app which loads the CSV file and show it as a list view
But I can't see my data I don't know why it is doing like this.
Here is the csv link [a link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t3YAIg0OBWewPSJqmOWbAkaSdglSeokPfbB9J2FlG_Q/edit?usp=sharing)!

When I run my app I see only this 
[image]

Instead, I want to fill the empty space like this 
[image]

Here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

class TableLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TableLayoutState createState() => _TableLayoutState();
}
class _TableLayoutState extends State<TableLayout> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  List<List<dynamic>> data = [];

  loadAsset() async {
    final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("asset/dreamss.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);

    data = csvTable;
    print(data);
  }

    return MaterialApp(
    home:Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("dsf"),),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton( onPressed: () async {
            await loadAsset();
            print(data);
          },),
      body: Table(
        children: data.map((item){
          return TableRow(
            children: item.map((row){
              return Text(row.toString());
            }).toList(),
          );
        }).toList(),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }

}
```

Comment: @Blasanka no error in the console  [here is the console screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/pxkqrfn/1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed [setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html).
Whenever you change the internal state of a State object, make the change in a function that you pass to [setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html).
Please see the full code as below:

```
class TableLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TableLayoutState createState() => _TableLayoutState();
}
class _TableLayoutState extends State<TableLayout> {
  List<List<dynamic>> data = [];

  loadAsset() async {
    final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("asset/dreamss.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);

    return csvTable;
  }

  void load() async{
    var newdata = await loadAsset();
    setState(() {
      data = newdata;
    });
    print(data);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("dsf"),),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton( onPressed: load),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
        Table(
          children: data.map((item){
            return TableRow(
              children: item.map((row){
                return Text(row.toString());
              }).toList(),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
    ]),
    ));
  }
}
```

It printed data as below:

```
I/flutter ( 9677): [[S.no, Dream, Direct, House, Ending], [1, Quarrel between husband and wife, 03, 08, 13, 37, 40, 73, , 3], [2, Erotic dream, 17, 40, 53, 59, 60, 83, , ], [3, Bathing in the open, 08, 18, 28, 48, 78, 98, , 8], [4, Travelling, 08, 14, 18, 52, 64, 68, 74, 78, 98, , 8], [5, Travelling in an aeroplane, 23, 43, 53, 63, 68, 73, 83, 93, , 3], [6, Taking a walk, , , 0,1], [7, Studying, , , 5], [8, Corpse, , 9, 9], [9, Playing, 00, 27, 40, 50, 57, 60, , ], [10, Talking over the phone, 98, 96, 94, , ], [11, Eating, 01, 02, 05, 15, 16, 45, 75, 85, 95, , ], [12, Breast Feeding, 02, 03, 05, 12, 20, 52, 53, , ], [13, Male, 6, 6, ], [14, Female, 5, 5, ], [15, Child, 2,3, 2,3, ], [16, Police, 7, 87, 8, , ], [17, Wild Pig, 46, , ], [18, Snake or ilea fish, 09, 17, 37, 57, 77, 99, , 7], [19, Cow, goat or buffalo, 12, 18, 19, 22, 24, 34, 42, 54, 72, 74, 84, 94, 97, , ], [20, Cow, 4, 4, ], [21, Tiger, 9, 9, ], [22, Dog, 4,5,6, 4, ], [23, Horse, 8, 8, ], [24, Bird, 2, 2, ], [25, Elephant, 9, 9, ], [26, Snail, 0, 0, 0], [27, Turtl
```

Please refer the my screenshot as below:
[image]

Comment: @yahochan why I am not getting the full data from the CSV

Comment: @Abhijitleihaorambam I am sorry, I've changed asset path to `assets`. I returned it back to `asset`.

Comment: @yahochan yeah I changed that but I am not able to get the full data from the CSV. I am only getting some data like up to S no 27.

Comment: @Abhijitleihaorambam It was 72 when I read it. But, current screen is not scrollable.

Comment: @Abhijitleihaorambam  I updated code what is scrollable.

Comment: How do you make that table load without having the floating button?