# convert data from a csv to a dynamic List (Flutter)

Tags: csv, flutter, dart

I create an app that loads the CSV file and displays it as a list view, I have used the following example. https://gist.github.com/Rahiche/9b4b2d3b5c24dddbbe662b58c5a2dcd2

The problem is that my List, don't generate rows

```
I/flutter ( 2158): [[M01, Plastics, 50, NA
I/flutter ( 2158): M02, Plastics, 85, NA
I/flutter ( 2158): M03, Wood, 50, NA
I/flutter ( 2158): M04, Wood, 15, 3
I/flutter ( 2158): M05, Plastics, 50, NA]]
```

Here is my code

```
class TableLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TableLayoutState createState() => _TableLayoutState();
}

class _TableLayoutState extends State<TableLayout> {
  List<List<dynamic>> data = [];
  loadAsset() async {
    final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/ford.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);
    print(csvTable);
    data = csvTable;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          onPressed: () async {
            await loadAsset();
            //print(data);
          }),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Table Layout and CSV"),
      ),

      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Table(
          columnWidths: {
            0: FixedColumnWidth(100.0),
            1: FixedColumnWidth(200.0),
          },
          border: TableBorder.all(width: 1.0),
          children: data.map((item) {
            return TableRow(
                children: item.map((row) {
                  return Container(
                    color:
                    row.toString().contains("NA") ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        row.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList());
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and my ford.csv

```
M01,Plastics,50,NA
M02,Plastics,85,NA
M03,Wood,50,NA
M04,Wood,15,3
M05,Plastics,50,NA
```

[image]

---
i tried the hints from https://pub.dev/packages/csv#-readme-tab- and from
[Not viewing Table Layout from a csv in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56306335/not-viewing-table-layout-from-a-csv-in-flutter/56306691#56306691) and I have read several csv files
but every time i have the same issues.

what am I doing wrong??

Please help a new flutter developer. ;)

Answer (score 6):

You can copy paste run full code below 
I add `setState` in function `loadAsset()` 
I did not encounter column width issue, if you still have this issue, please try to add column 2 , 3 or shrink width of FixedColumnWidth

```
columnWidths: {
            0: FixedColumnWidth(100.0),
            1: FixedColumnWidth(100.0),
            2: FixedColumnWidth(50.0),
          },
```

code snippet

```
loadAsset() async {
    final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/ford.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);
    print(csvTable);
    data = csvTable;
    setState(() {

    });
  }
```

working demo 
animated gif did not show correct green color, 
so I paste final result in second picture

[image]

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:csv/csv.dart';
import 'dart:async' show Future;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: TableLayout(),
    );
  }
}


class TableLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TableLayoutState createState() => _TableLayoutState();
}

class _TableLayoutState extends State<TableLayout> {
  List<List<dynamic>> data = [];
  loadAsset() async {
    final myData = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/ford.csv");
    List<List<dynamic>> csvTable = CsvToListConverter().convert(myData);
    print(csvTable);
    data = csvTable;
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          onPressed: () async {
            await loadAsset();
            //print(data);
          }),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Table Layout and CSV"),
      ),

      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Table(
          columnWidths: {
            0: FixedColumnWidth(100.0),
            1: FixedColumnWidth(200.0),
          },
          border: TableBorder.all(width: 1.0),
          children: data.map((item) {
            return TableRow(
                children: item.map((row) {
                  return Container(
                    color:
                    row.toString().contains("NA") ? Colors.red : Colors.green,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Text(
                        row.toString(),
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList());
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: big thanks, I get it to work, my problem was a wrong CSV file.

Comment: How do you make that table load without having the floating button?

Comment: @CuriousPaul you could try and putting the "loadAsset()" inside of the widget's initState method, see:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html

Answer (score 2):

It's because of different EOL (END OF LINE) characters that are used to terminate a line in file. i.e Some program use '\r\n' while other '\n'.
So to solve the issue you have to consider that. i.e I am using csv package on window os and while reading from a csv file, you should specify eol argument to `convert` method of the `CsvToListConverter()`.

```
return CsvToListConverter().convert(csv.data, eol: '\n');
```

Answer (score 1):

The [fast_csv](https://pub.dev/packages/fast_csv) parser is for parsing CSV data.
It is 2.9-4.7 times faster than the [csv](https://pub.dev/packages/csv) parser.

If you need to parse large amounts of data, then it will be more efficient.

Line endings are `\n`, `\r\n` or `\r` (no need to configure).

```dart
import 'package:fast_csv/fast_csv.dart' as _fast_csv;

void main(List<String> args) {
  final res = _fast_csv.parse(_csv);
  print(res);
}

final _csv = '''
M01,Plastics,50,NA
M02,Plastics,85,NA
M03,Wood,50,NA
M04,Wood,15,3
M05,Plastics,50,NA
''';
```

Output:

```
[[M01, Plastics, 50, NA], [M02, Plastics, 85, NA], [M03, Wood, 50, NA], [M04, Wood, 15, 3], [M05, Plastics, 50, NA]]
```