# how to convert CSV file to json in flutter?

Tags: flutter, sqlite, csv, dart, sqflite

recently i develop an ToDo application using flutter and sqflite , for backup my data i convert my database data to csv file(import data to csv file using csv package) now i want to again use this file in my application and store csv file data to my sqlite database how can i convert csv file to json? cause sqlite work with json or i should use from other approach please guide me.

```
static Future conertToCSVFile(List<Roznamcha> roznamcha) async {
List<List<dynamic>> data = [
  ...roznamcha.map((e) => [
        e.transactionNumber,
        e.issueDate,
        e.description,
        e.credit,
        e.debit,
        e.rate,
        e.accountNum,
      ])
];
Directory dir = Platform.isAndroid
    ? await getExternalStorageDirectory() //FOR ANDROID
    : await getApplicationSupportDirectory(); //FOR iOS

final paths = '${dir.path}/csv.csv';

String csvData = ListToCsvConverter().convert(data);

final File file = File(paths);

await file.writeAsString(csvData);
```

}

```
 static loadCsvFromStorage() async {
FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
  allowedExtensions: ['csv'],
  type: FileType.custom,
);
String path = result.files.first.path;
final csvFile = new File(path).openRead();
return await csvFile
    .transform(utf8.decoder)
    .transform(
      CsvToListConverter(),
    )
    .toList();
```

}
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert data from a csv to a dynamic List (Flutter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59076371/convert-data-from-a-csv-to-a-dynamic-list-flutter)

Comment: i convert csv file to list but how  to store this dynamic list to database this is my question exactly @ChiragBargoojar