# How to fetch data into listview?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

how do i fetch my data inside listview..... i been trying fetch list of data but it seems doesnt work for me or maybe the way i fetch it for data is wrong and for now i just fetch a raw data inside the listview that it fetch all row data inside one list.... can somebody help me how to fetch data inside the list

this is my code

```
FutureBuilder(
              future: loadingCsvData(path),
              builder: (context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<Map<int, Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
                print(snapshot.data.toString());
                return snapshot.hasData
                    ? ListView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        children: [
                          Card(
                            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                              ListTile(
                                title: Text(snapshot.data.toString()),
                              )
                            ]),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    : Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
              },
            ),
```

my list model

```
static Map<String, dynamic> userToMap(List<dynamic> row) {
    return {
      if (row[0] != null) 'No': row[0] as int,
      if (row[1] != null) 'Name': row[1] as String,
      if (row[2] != null) 'Code': row[2] as String
    };
  }

  // A map with an int key and Map<String, dynamic> value
  static Map<int, Map<String, dynamic>> userListToMap(
      List<List<dynamic>> userList) {
    userList.removeAt(
        0); //If you want to remove the first row containing the headers
    return userList.map((user) => userToMap(user)).toList().asMap();
  }
```

Comment: Use ListView.builder() https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists

Comment: then how do i call my list to fetch it in ListView.Builder

Answer (score 1):

For example this is your list

```
  Map _data = {
    0: {'No': 1, 'Name': 'Ali', 'Code': 'A123'},
    1: {'No': 2, 'Name': 'Abu', 'Code': 'B456'},
    2: {'No': 3, 'Name': 'Amir', 'Code': 'C789'},
    3: {'No': 4, 'Name': 'Safe', 'Code': 'D098'},
    4: {'No': 5, 'Name': 'Alif', 'Code': 'E765'}
  };
```

And you can fetch data from this list to `ListView.builder` like this

```
   ListView.builder(
      itemCount: _data.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Column(
          children: [
            Text(_data[index]['Name']),
            Text(_data[index]['Code']),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: You can show me your list by editing your question.

Comment: how do i fix this problem type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast

Comment: these are my list I/flutter (13280): {0: {No: 1, Name:  Ali, Code:  A123}, 1: {No: 2, Name:  Abu, Code:  B456}, 2: {No: 3, Name:  Amir, Code:  C789}, 3: {No: 4, Name:  Safe, Code:  D098}, 4: {No: 5, Name:  Alif, Code:  E765 }}

Comment: I have edited my answer as per your `Map` data

Comment: yeah it worked.... but all data is from csv file that i upload from phone storage so that how i want to know how to call map from csv file ... i already make map for my csv data but i want fetch it into listview

Comment: I am not getting your issue.

Comment: this my converter csv data to map list https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68313866/how-to-convert-csv-data-from-filepicker-to-dynamic-list and now i want to fetch all data into listview

Comment: In this case `Map _data = userToMap(your_list);` This is how you can get list

Comment: i got this error The method '[]' was called on null.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not sure about Android, but when you return JSON, it's good manner to set proper headers.

By now your php script (http://pixography.netai.net/json.php) returns following:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 06 Dec 2015 20:37:02 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Content-Length: 238
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

Try putting header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); before any output in your script, also check for UTF-8 BOM issue, because it breaks proper header output in php.

At least you will get proper headers for your JSON.

--

Another thing that I see in your php code - you array keys are numeric, I'm not quite sure, but I think for JSON object keys should be strings. So maybe you should try `$response[$row[0]] = array("Name"=>$row[0],"Location"=>$row[1]); instead ?`

--

I also think that you should put mysqli_close($con); before echo, for better performance. After you fulfilled your data for output, there is no reason at all to keep the MySQL connection open.

Comment: for me the list is from me upload csv file so the data is from csv file